# Grails command binding - Domain classes with relations - it's possible?

Tags: java, data-binding, grails

If I have domain classes like:

```
class A {
 short aCode
 //...
 static hasMany = [bs : B]
 static mapping = {
   id column: 'a_code' name: 'aCode'
 }
}

class B {
  long bCode
  static belongsTo = [a: A]
  id column: 'b_code' name: 'bCode'
}
```

And try to use the B class in a command:

```
class SomeCommand {
  List<B> bs = ListUtils.lazyList( [], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(B) )
}
```

My input for aCode should be:

```
<input type='text' name='bs[0].a.aCode' />
```

Why this is not binded by grails controller? `command.bs[0].a` stays null after binding.

I'm using Grails 2.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the data binding with command objects and Lists does not work. There's a [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5582) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have done relations binding with no problem.

I am not sure how this works.

```
class SomeCommand {
  List<B> bs = ListUtils.lazyList( [], FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(B) )
}

<input type='text' name='bs[0].a.aCode' />
```

For, A (Parent) has many B (Children) and B belongs to A.

eg. A has 10Bs (bs[0] ~ bs[9])
I can always use something like this to bind the input.

```
<input type="text" name="a.aCode" />

<input type="text" name="bs[0].bCode" />
<input type="text" name="bs[1].bCode" />
....
....
```

Not sure how to bind the data from children (B) to parent (A).

Comment: Like your example, i'm binding manually the A in the B. The guys from the Grails mail list pointed me a JIRA for this: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5582